# problem with api call after migrating apis from version 3.1.0 to 3.2.0

Tags: wso2

I exported my api from wso2 api manager 3.1.0 with apictl tool version 3.1.3 and then imported it to wso2 api manager 3.2.0 with apictl tool version 3.2.1.the api is imported successfully but in dev portal after calling the api with an application, i got the following error:

```
<ams:fault xmlns:ams="http://wso2.org/apimanager/security">
<ams:code>900902</ams:code>
<ams:message>Missing Credentials</ams:message>
<ams:description>Authentication Error. Make sure your API invocation call has a header: testkey is missing</ams:description>
</ams:fault>
```

I did not set any security level to my api.

How i can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think it was my fault.the life cycle of the api that i imported was "prototyped". i had to change the api life cycle from prototyped to PUBLISHED in publisher:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h29nq.png)

It worked after changing!